# Curious Recurring Template with Operators

Tags: c++, templates

I have this working on G++ but on Visual Studo 2008 this will not compile.

```
template<typename T, typename DerivedT >
struct Foo
{    
    template<typename Scale>
    DerivedT operator * (const Scale i)
    {
     DerivedT result;
     return result;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar : public Foo<T, Bar<T> >
{   
    // Removing this operator gets rid of the error.
    Bar& operator * (const Bar& boo)
    {
     return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<float> bar;
    bar = bar * 3;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Even if I define the Foo operator as an int/double/float explicitly it returns the same error message. Is there any way of getting past this?

**EDIT:**
This only falls apart when the derived class overload the operator * that is also defined in the Base class.

Comment: Show use case or we can't help you.

Comment: @DeadMG This is my test case, just trimmed. I've filled some of the missing info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to compile this by g++ (and I actually doubt that), but your code is indeed not compilable for rather obvious reasons. Your `Bar` class exposes only one `operator *`

```
Bar& operator * (const Bar& boo)
```

and that operator expects a `Bar` object as a right-hand size operand. `3` will not work, `3` is not `Bar` and is not convertible to `Bar`.

The base class's `operator *` is the one that might have worked here, but it is hidden by the derived class's operator. This is why, as one would expect, removing the derived class's `operator *` gets rid of the error.

You can simply add the

```
using Foo<T, Bar<T> >::operator *;
```

to the definition of `Bar` to unhide the base class's operator and it should compile.

Comment: @AndreyT and @Johannes: How can he use `DerivedT` in `Foo` class? Its an incomplete type. It wouldn't compile. Don't  you think so?

Comment: @Nawaz the member function definition is not instantiated until it is used. Only its declaration is instantiated. Using incomplete classes as a return type in non-defining declarations is fine: `struct A; struct B { A operator*(const float); };`

Comment: @Johannes: What about the line `DerivedT result;` in the function?

Comment: @Johannes: Alright. I understand it now. a member function `T f(){}` is basically `T f(Foo *this){}` means it's not a part the class!

Comment: @Nawaz For the `DerivedT result`, it's part of the definition of the function template, so I don't think it matters. Definition of members are not instantiated automatically, but only when their definition is needed. So when you instantiate `Foo<float, Bar<float>>`, you get a class `struct Foo<float, Bar<float>> { template<typename Scale> Bar<float> operator*(const Scale); };`. Only in function definitions, return types need to be complete. This is not a such a definition. When you call `operator*`, you instantiate the member template definition, and from it, the `operator*` function you call.